# Melting of plastics in absence of air

Tags: recycling, plastic

Kindly advice me whether melting of plastic in absence of air produce harmful fumes or other chemicals? Whether it is a safer practice compared to normal melting?

Comment: I'm not sure if it holds for all plastics, but generally yes melting plastics will produce toxic fumes. Related post: [Can I recycle plastics at home by melting and molding?](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/225/99).

Comment: I assume you mean "in an inert atmosphere" rather than "in a vacuum"?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show that this has anything to do with sustainability? Otherwise it's just a chemistry or engineering question (and off-topic here).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its chemistry