# Best type of recyclable plastic to melt into a clay mold to produce a small figurine

Tags: recycling, plastic

What would be the best type of plastic to melt into a clay mold, to produce a small figurine, something that a person would have normally, already in their household - such as soda bottles, milk bottles, plastic container, plastic silverware, etc?

I'm making butterflies using feathers as the wings, and I would like to make the bodies using recycled plastic somehow.

Comment: Related: https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/225/15

Answer (score 3):

So you want to know what plastic you can use to melt into your mold right? The hard ones are recommended: plastic containers and bottle caps. You will shred them into small pieces and them melt them.

The soda bottles can be melted but it might give you a different result if you mix it with other plastic sources.

Here is some example based on what you are about to do (clay mold): http://www.atomicshrimp.com/st/content/plastic_moulding

Of course you must always use apropriate equipment.